# Rails bundler won't bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been fighting this thing for days. I'm on rbenv and I have multiple rubies installed trying to get one stupid decade old app running. When I do "bundle install" I get an error that looks like it's trying to install the current version of rake. Instead of using the version installed with Rails 3....see below

```
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.0

fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0)
actionpack (3.0.0)
activemodel (3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.0)
activeresource (3.0.0)
activesupport (3.0.0)
arel (1.0.1)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.22) <-----------Note bundler is installed
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.4.2)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
mail (2.2.20)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (2.5.1)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.2.8)    
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.0)
railties (3.0.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)  <--------Note rake is installed
rdoc (3.9.5)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.60)
```

Here is my Gemfile...

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'


gem 'will_paginate', '~> 2.3.17'
gem 'soap4r-middleware', '~> 0.8.6'
gem 'soap4r',  '~> 1.5.6'
gem 'prawn-labels', '~> 0.11.3.0'
gem 'nokogiri-plist', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'rails_sql_views', '~> 0.8.0'
# gem 'prototype_legacy_helper', '0.0.0', :git => 'https://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git'
```

so Ruby and rails are installed...BUT when I do "bundle install" on my Rails 3 app I get...

```
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Installing rake (13.0.3)
Gem::InstallError: rake requires Ruby version >= 2.2.
An error occured while installing rake (13.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '13.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.

fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ bundler --version
rbenv: bundler: command not found
```

Why does it say bundler not found yet I can run Bundle install?
Why can I not get this rails 3 app working?

Any info will help my sanity. Thank you.

UPDATE:

After following Paul D solution I ran bundle install again...but got this error...

```
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.17.3)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 1.0.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (= 3.0.0)', in any of the sources.
```

Comment: 13.0.3 is the latest version of rake. You might need to manually install an older version which supports Ruby 1.9. Try 11.3.0. Also, what does bundle --version say? And Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Have you a `Gemfile.lock` in your project?

Comment: No `Gemfile.lock` as it's the first time running bundle install

Comment: @Schwern installed rake 11.3.0  but bundle `_1.0.22_` install gives same error

Comment: `bundle install` should install from the Gemfile.lock to avoid the very problem you're having. However, [it seems it was not the practice then to check Gemfile.lock in](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/3372) back then. You might have to manually specify some gem versions in your Gemfile.

Comment: Without a Gemfile.lock, `bundle install` will try to resolve the dependencies in the Gemfile regardless of what gems you have installed. Some of them will not have limited the versions of their own dependencies like rake, so it's trying to install the latest version. You should be able to fix this by specifying your exact versions in your Gemfile such as `gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'`.

Comment: I initially commented but then later decided to turn that into an actual answer for you below.

Comment: To all...there is no Gemfile.lock. This is the first time that bundle install is ran

Answer (score 0):

@thefonso, I manage multiple decade old apps running stable on Ruby `1.9.3-p551` daily. Here are a few things to ensure:

1. Make sure you're running latest release of Ruby 1.9 which is 1.9.3-p551. It needs to be installed with SSL/TLS patches as per below:

```rb
# Make sure you have latest OpenSSL
sudo apt-get purge -y libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libssl1.0-dev

# Now install Ruby 1.9.3-p551
rbenv install --force --patch 1.9.3-p551 < <(curl -sSL https://git.io/JOtSv)
rbenv global 1.9.3-p551 # (optional)
rbenv rehash

# Now install Bundler 1.17.3
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3 --no-rdoc --no-ri

# Add require 'openssl' to .../versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/bundle file right under require 'rubygems'
# This command below will do it automatically for you as long as you provide it the correct file path
sed "/^require .*/a require 'openssl'" -i "PATH_TO_RBENV_DIR_HERE/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/bundle"

# That's it! Run commands below to ensure you have patched Ruby 1.9.3-p551
rbenv rehash
curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby
```

2. Now that's out of the way, you can try installing `rake 10.5.0`

```rb
gem install rake -v 10.5.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Comment: just updated my post. I'm getting a crazy error now regarding bundler (see the UPDATE above)

Comment: As @Schwern mentioned above it is most likely your Gemfile.lock file causing the issue. Run `mv Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock.old` in root directly of the project to rename but NOT delete the existing lock file and then run `bundle` after that.

Comment: Hmm, well this is the very first time the app is being bundle installed so there is no Gemfile.lock.  @Schewrn posted a possible solution below that may address this. I've stumbled onto a different solution path that I'm currently exploring and that is just moving the app to 3.1.0. I've been able to succeed in running bundle install from there and am now working on a "method_missing_with_paginate" error from my "rake db:schema:dump" attempt.

Answer (score 0):

A Gemfile.lock would avoid this problem. If you had one from the last time you ran this code, it would still have the appropriate versions for Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9. Bundler would follow the Gemfile.lock. Unfortunately back then it was not the practice to commit Gemfile.lock.

Since you don't have a Gemfile.lock you're in dependency hell. Bundler is trying to resolve the dependencies using each gem's own gemspec. ***It doesn't matter which gems you have installed***. Where versions are specified it will use that. Where they are not, it will try to use the latest version. Most gems aren't thinking about Ruby 1.9 any more, or old versions of gems didn't have good dependency specifications, so there's going to be problems.

For example, Rails 3.0.0's [rails.gemspec](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.0/rails.gemspec) depends on railties 3.0.0. railties 3.0.0's [railties.gemspec](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.0/railties/railties.gemspec) depends on rake >= 0.8.4. There's no upper bound, so Bundler grabs the latest rake and it doesn't work with Ruby 1.9.

To solve this you will need to add more versioned dependencies to your Gemfile. For example, rake 11 should work with Ruby 1.9. Try adding this to your Gemfile.

```
gem 'rake', '~> 11'
```

Or you can be super conservative and specify the exact versions you have installed.

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
```

Run bundle. This should get you past rake and onto the next dependency problem. Add a version restriction for that and bundle. Continue until there's no more dependency issues. Check in the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: That second paragraph above was the key. That nuance is what I missed. Thank you so much. I'm going to try this.